# GitHub tool to review post commits?

Tags: github

I am looking for a GitHub PostCommit CodeReview tool which does the following:

**Looking specifically for PostCommit CodeReview**

1. Has LDap support
2. Displays git branches and files.
3. Select text and add comment. (like Google Doc)
4. Email all comments with selected snippet to user.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a full web interface, you could go for something like [Github Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/) or [Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/). Both really helpful applications for anything Git. You can basicly do the things you want in there. You can get an easy file browser of the repository, and add comments on specific lines of code.